# English translation of the Tanakh with transliterated Hebrew

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, translation

I'm looking for an English translation of the Tanakh that includes the Hebrew, the English and transliterated Hebrew.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Clark and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for a great question.

There's this one, which comes from a reputable author:

[https://www.amazon.com/Transliterated-Hebrew-English-Torah-Yosef-Dovid-ebook/dp/B07ZPBSFMZ/ref=sr_1_7?qid=1684734203&refinements=p_27%3AYosef+Ben+Dovid&s=digital-text&sr=1-7&text=Yosef+Ben+Dovid](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZPBSFMZ)

There is also a free, inconvenient, but serviceable way to do this online with two web sites.

From https://www.alittlehebrew.com/transliterate/ , you can click reference and then type in the text you want, for example Leviticus 24:1-5, for verses 1-5 of chapter 24.

Then from https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm you can get the translation for the same verse.

If you do a top bottom split screen, you should be able to see Hebrew, English, and transliterated Hebrew at once.
(Put each site in a separate browser window, then press the windows key and the up arrow together.)